# Extract a part of a string and append it to a tag

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find a string that starts with "section_" and add this as a value to a tag in the same line.
Example: Following is the input in a file of type ditamap.

```
<topicref href="xyz/debug_logging_in_xyz-section_i_y_mn.dita"/>
<topicref href="xyz/workflows_id-section_exf_zaz_lo.dita"/>
<topicref href="xyz/images_id-section_ekl_bbz_lo.dita"/>
```

Desired output:

```
<topicref href="xyz/debug_logging_in_xyz-section_i_y_mn.dita" keys="section_i_y_mn"/>
<topicref href="xyz/workflows_id-section_exf_zaz_lo.dita" keys="section_exf_zaz_lo"/>
<topicref href="xyz/images_id-section_ekl_bbz_lo.dita" keys="section_ekl_bbz_lo"/>
```

I understand BeautifulSoup can be used to achieve this. But, I am new and do not know the syntax. Can anyone help?

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
globpath = "C:/DATA" #add your directory path here 

def main(path):
    with open(path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        s = f.read()
    s = bs(s, "xml")
    imgs = s.find_all("topicref")
    for i in imgs:
        if "section" in i["href"]:
            i["keys"] = i["href"].replace("*-","").replace(".dita*","")
    s = str(s)
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(s)

for dirpath, directories, files in os.walk(globpath):
         for fname in files:
            if fname.endswith(".ditamap"):
                path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
                main(path)
```

But, it's adding the entire path in the keys attribute. I need only the portion that starts with section and ends before .dita.

Regex worked:Here is the final code

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
globpath = "C:/DATA" #add your directory path here
 

def main(path):
    with open(path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        s = f.read()
    s = bs(s, "xml")
    imgs = s.find_all("topicref")
    for i in imgs:
        if "section" in i["href"]:
            try:
                i["keys"] = re.findall("section[^\.]*",i["href"])[0]
            except:
                print("Could not replace")
    s = str(s)
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(s)```
````

Comment: First of all, explain from where do you want to get the 'section_' string and where to append it? post some of your code for a detailed explanation

Comment: I want to find section and the portion of the string with it in the keys= attribute.

Comment: Hey, check my answer below, is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be done with Regex (cuz thats the most i can do)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('your-string-input-of-tags-goes-here', 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('topicref', {'keys': re.compile(r'(section_([^ "])+)')})
```

Returns a list of matched tags

Check this code whether it works or not